# Interactive Ruby REPL or console engine for web

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

Im looking for creating something like http://tryruby.org/ which is executing ruby script from web probably on top of sinatra or rails 3. Is there any engine or gem for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Check it https://github.com/jwo/ruby-fiddle-web